# Like operator search on encrypted column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption

I have a table in sqlserver, my table has a field as string, for example FirstName (it's just example!). This field "EncryptByPassPhrase" before insert on database.

```
Before encode: Ali
After  encode: 0x010000001D905174BB7947AE1C600A4AB564A123310F92C21C9A4221
```

Now i would search on this field for example i would get all fields that contains charcters 'Al'.

### I can decode this field and search on such as:

```
select * from EncodeTest e
where  dbo.Decoder(e.FirstName) like '%Al%'
```

---

But this way very slow on many numbers of record.
Please help me for best solution.

Thanks.

---

### What I have tried:

```
declare @EncodedName varbinary(max)
select @EncodedName =EncryptByPassPhrase('key', cast( @Name as varbinary(max)) )


declare @DecodedName nvarchar(max)
select @DecodedName=convert(varchar(100),DecryptByPassPhrase('key',cast( @EncodedName as varbinary(max)) ))

select * from EncodeTest e
where dbo.Decoder(e.FirstName) like '%Al%'
```

Comment: the data is encrypted. How do you expect SQL Server to search before decrypt it ?

Comment: you need to change your point of view. if your encrypted column, could decrypt in SQL, I said you are doing something wrong. if you need a column in your table that you need to search on it, then you shouldn't encrypt the data; it's not efficient. if you need to protect your data you can improve your knowledge about Security and permissions in SQL.

Comment: I expect SQL Server to search without decrypt it :)

Comment: Thanks dear @imankazemi 
I would encrypte column for avoid show data on select and allow search on it!
I know this is amazing, but i as developer must search on this content and get Convincing answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encryption (security in general) is a compromise with convenience. If you want to be secure, you must sacrifice the easy of access. If you want to be easy accessible and fast, then you must sacrifice security. Your job as developer is to find the right balance between these. In your case, obviously the server need to decrypt **all of your data** to be able to search for the text you want. If you need to search in encrypted data, then your design is broken. Either find another way to protect your data, or give up searching it efficiently.

I would say, why are you encrypting names? The database already has security layers to protect your data ([Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017), database users rights, etc.) which will protect the data from unauthorized access. You should encrypt only really sensitive information, such credit card numbers, social security numbers and its equivalents, etc. Abusing with encryption by using it for every single field (or relatively harmless fields like names) will make your application quite inconvenient and usually doesn't worth the efforts.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @andrey, I created a dictionary table and could find records faster. but i wouldn't save decrypted text in sql.

Comment: Thanks a lot again for new editing :)
Your answer is correct, but "name" just an example, I must researching for this subject as developer and get best answer for it!